# Manga about a reincarnated boy, abandoned by his parents due to a lack of skills

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I read this manga, but I can't remember its name. It's about this man who got reincarnated into another world, but he is mistreated by his parents due to having no skill and is condemned as worthless. The only one who is kind to him is his older brother. When the boy is ten or twelve in the first chapter, he leaves the house. His older brother offers him money but the boy refuses.

I don't remember much of the manga, but all I remember that the boy lived in a village and he has memories of past life. And he says something about him being in a world he knew from a game he played. Oh and I remember when the boy had to come of age he had to see what his skills or job was, but he refuses to go through the ceremony because of his lack of skill or something. His father is glad his sons leaves the house because he doesn't want anything to do with him. And I think the boy ends up with cheat skills I think, I can't really remember.

I don't know if this is connected to the manga I'm looking for but I remember a scene when a boy used a well to invade a bandits hide out. I'm not sure if it's the same manga though.

Does someone know what manga I'm talking about? I really want to read this manga again, but it doesn't help me that I've forgotten the name of it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this manga full colour or mostly in black & white, and what colour was the main boy's hair? Also, do you recall anything about what happened to him after he left his parents' house?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: lol. Does he turn out to have incredibly OP skills?

Answer (score 1):

I found it: [The Unrivaled Reincarnated Sage of Another World: The Strongest in Another World Through Game Knowledges](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-unrivaled-reincarnated-sage-of-another-world-the-strongest-in-another-world-through-game-knowledges) (Isekai Kenja no Tensei Musou ~Geemu no Chishiki de Isekai Saikyou)

> Due to an unfortunate death, a young man reincarnates under the name Eld in a world very similar to the VRMMO that he played before his passing. However, this world he found himself in didn't even know what basic skills were! As the only person with knowledge beyond the populace, Eld sets off on a journey as a level 1 novice to job change into the strongest class in the world, Sage!
>
> Source: Comikey

Comment: Hi, it's great that you found it!  Can you add some details, like when it was produced, a plot synopsis, maybe some links?  And don't forget to accept your own answer.